# Dynamic QueryDSL query builder

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I am trying to write a generic DAO class that accepts dynamic predicates.

In my BaseDAO class, I create `PathBuilder` to add some predicates using the following contructor: `PathBuilder<Q> entityPath = new PathBuilder<Q>(clazz, "entity");`

When executing, I get the following exception:

> 2019-06-06 17:55:11.779 ERROR 11212 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-2]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: **Invalid path:**
>   **'entity.id'** [select member1 from com.example.clientcachedemo.Member
>   member1 where entity.id = ?1]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path:
>   'entity.id' [select member1 from com.example.clientcachedemo.Member
>   member1 where entity.id = ?1]] with root cause
>
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path:
>   'entity.id' [select member1 from com.example.clientcachedemo.Member
>   member1 where entity.id = ?1]

---

It seems that hibernate used 'member1' as table alias when constructing the HQL.
If I change the PathBuilder creation to `PathBuilder<Q> entityPath = new PathBuilder<Q>(clazz, "member1");` all works good, but this should be a generic code.

How can I infer the alias name of the table that hibernate use?

How can I force hibernate to use a different alias ('entity')?

### Base Entity:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5322749711870322616L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BIGINT UNSIGNED")
    protected Long id;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    public Timestamp timestamp;

    @Version
    Long version;
}
```

---

### Member entity

```
@Data
@Entity
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Table(name = "MEMBERS", indexes = { @Index(name = "ix1", unique = false, columnList = "timestamp") })
public class Member extends BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3641904361081907333L;
    private String name;
    private String city;
    private String email;
    private String gender;
    private String hour;
    private String title;
}
```

---

### BaseDAO

```
public class BaseDAO<E extends BaseEntity, Q extends EntityPath<?>> {

    @Autowired
    BaseQDSLRepository<E, Q> repository;

    public Iterable<E> query(RestCriteria criteria) {

        Class<E> clazz = getEntityClass();
        PathBuilder<E> entityPath = new PathBuilder<E>(clazz, "entity");
        Predicate p = entityPath.get("id").eq(1L); // TODO Parse criteria to predicate...
        return repository.findAll(p);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
    protected Class<E> getEntityClass() {
        Class<E> clazz = null;
        Type[] genericTypes = ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments();
        if (genericTypes[0] instanceof ParameterizedType) {
            clazz = (Class<E>) ((ParameterizedType) genericTypes[1]).getRawType();
        } else {
            clazz = (Class<E>) genericTypes[0];
        }
        return clazz;
    }

}
```

---

### BaseQDSLRepository

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseQDSLRepository<E extends BaseEntity, Q extends EntityPath<?>>
        extends BaseJpaRepository<E>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<E>, BinderCustomizer<Q> {

}
```

### Controller

```
@PostMapping
@ResponseBody
public Iterable<Member> query(@RequestBody RestCriteria criteria) {
    Iterable<Member> mems = dao.query(criteria);
    return mems;
}
```

Comment: I your repositories extend QuerydslPredicateExecutor you already inherit a method that accepts dynamic predicates. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/querydsl/QuerydslPredicateExecutor.html. If you use the Spring Data web extension you can also have the Predicate created from the request params: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.type-safe

Comment: I do use dynamic predicates, the issue is how to set the path builder name so I won't get "Invalid path" exception.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve that cannot be done via Spring's out of the box support for QueryDsl?? Maybe I'm missing something but I don;t see that you have to write any code to work with dynamic predicates.

Comment: Thanks Alan!
In BaseDAO.query I am initiating a PathBuilder:


PathBuilder<E> entityPath = new PathBuilder<E>(clazz, "entity")

I use "entity" as the name of the PathBuilder and the result for the predicate is "entity.id = ?1" HQL:

select member1 from com.example.clientcachedemo.Member member1 where entity.id = ?1

and I get Invalid path exception...

When I set the PathBuilder name to be "member1" the result query is good.

So the question is how should I initiate the PathBuilder?

PathBuilder<Q>(clazz, "?????")?

I can't set "member1" as this should be dynamic.